# JDBC MySQL connection works on some Tomcats but fails on others with MySQLNonTransientConnectionException

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, jetty

I have a GWT web application project usually running on a tomcat, but I can't get it to connect to my MySQL database reliably.

It works in the following instances:

- Run as "Web Application" from Eclipse
- built with gradle and the war deployed on a remote tomcat 6 server
- built with gradle and the war deployed on a local tomcat 7 server

It doesn't work in the following cases

- Run on a local jetty created by gradle via the `jettyRunWar` task (which first builds the war and then starts a built-in jetty to deploy it to)
- built with gradle and the war deployed on a remote tomcat 7 server

The web application starts up fine in all cases but the first database access fails with the following exception in the last two cases:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1015)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2575)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2311)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:347)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:443)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:141)
at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:111)
    [snip: our code creating the connection to the database]

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.<init>(Buffer.java:55)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1740)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1290)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2493)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2526)
... 44 more
```

I also went back in our commit history a few months, but can't find a version that doesn't have the problem. However, I'm pretty sure that it used to run without problems using the `jettyRunWar` command of gradle.

Here is the relevant code for the database connection:

```
public static Connection getConnection(String host, int port, String database, String user, String password) throws SQLException
{
    MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    dataSource.setServerName(host);
    dataSource.setPort(port);
    dataSource.setDatabaseName(database);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);
    dataSource.setConnectTimeout(Preferences.MYSQL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
    return dataSource.getConnection();
}
```

I tried it in several environments as you can see and tried several version of the code (e.g. with different GWT jars etc.) but I still have no clue why it works in some configurations but not in others.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs with mysql drivers starting with version 5.1.17. Downgrading to 5.1.16 solves this problem for me.

Edit: I filed a bug concerning that in the mysqlbug tracker (http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72630). I got very fast response that the cause might be some unsupported encoding exception. That was true for me, so after fixing the file.encoding system property (running tomcat with -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8), all worked as expected.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, downgrading to 5.1.16 worked for me as well! Do you happen to know how to set the file.encoding on the gradle jettyRunWar task?

Comment: Have a look at the bug report. We found out that the cause was an invalid encoding that was passed to the tomcat via jvm property "-Dfile.encoding=UFT-8" (instead of UTF-8). So downgrading is not necessary in this case.